# nuxt.js document is not defined, problem with pugin

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I added plugin: `vue-burger-menu` to my `nuxt.js` project. And i have an error: `"document is not defined"`. I know,  that this plugin is available only for client-side. So I found in vue documentation [enter link description here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#client-side-only) what I have to do to fix it. It works only for first refresh. Then I have again document is not defined.

`nuxt.config.js`:

```
  build: {
vendor: ['vue-burger-menu'],
 }

 plugins: [
{ src: '~/plugins/vue-burger-menu.js', ssr: false }
],
```

Add a file to my plugins folder called `"vue-burger-menu.js"`:

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
 import VueBurgerMenu from 'vue-burger-menu';

   if (process.browser) {

      Vue.use(VueBurgerMenu);

   }
```

`nav template`

```
 <template lang="pug">
   Slide(right)
        nav.menu_vertical
 </template>

 <script>
 import { Slide } from 'vue-burger-menu'
 export default {
 name: 'Nav',
 components: {
   Slide
 },
}
```

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Replace deprecated **process.browser** with **process.client**

```
if (process.client) {
   Vue.use(VueBurgerMenu);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud, your answer saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt is doing SSR and `document` is only available in `browser` so you need to wrap your plugin code like

change `"vue-burger-menu.js"` as following

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueBurgerMenu from 'vue-burger-menu';

if (process.browser) {

 Vue.use(VueBurgerMenu);

}
```

you can find detail documentation [Here](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/)

Comment: I don't know why, but it's still doesn't work :/ I add a scrren to my post with this error.

Comment: where is the screenshot you posted?

Comment: It is in the bottom of code. With this error: document is not defined.