# Changing from "spa" to "universal" in Nuxt , but I only get document is not defined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I wanted to have urls that I could copy and paste and therefore switched from spa to universal in nuxt.config. However I get this error saying "document is not defined". I then googled my way to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058544/document-is-not-defined-in-nuxt-js) saying I should use the `<no-ssr>` element.
However after using it on my index.vue, I still get the same error. Anyone who can help me out?

It's node_modules/aws-amplify-vue/dist/aws-amplify-vue.common.js who is complaining about the document missing.

And to test at the moment my index.vue is following:

```
<template>
 <v-layout column justify-center align-center>
  <div>
    <no-ssr placeholder="loading...">
      <div>hello</div>
    </no-ssr>
  </div>
 </v-layout>
</template>
```

And I have other pages in the project without `<no-ssr>` if that's what causing this.

Comment: use `client-only` istead of `no-ssr`

Comment: you can also check with `if(process.server)` if its on server side

Comment: If its a plugin then you can configure that particular plugin to not run as ssr. 

export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/both-sides.js' },
    { src: '~/plugins/client-only.js', mode: 'client' }, // only on client side
    { src: '~/plugins/server-only.js', mode: 'server' } // only on server side
  ]
}

Comment: Thanks for comments. However `client-only`and adding mode didn't solve my problem. Tried both 'client' and 'server' and adding ssr: false 
`plugins: [{ src: '~plugins/aws.js', mode: 'client', ssr: false }]`

Comment: Searched some more and it kind of looks like the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247375/nuxt-js-document-is-not-defined-problem-with-pugin). But no solution :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue, the solution in my case was as following:

1. adding if (process.client) to my middleware (middleware/auth.js) and require AmplifyEventBus afterwards:

```
export const fetchUser = async () => {
  let signedIn = false;
    if (process.client) {
      const { AmplifyEventBus } = require("aws-amplify-vue");
      try {
        const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
        signedIn = true
      } catch (err) {
        signedIn = false
      }

      AmplifyEventBus.$on("authState", info => {
        if (info === "signedIn") {
          signedIn = true;
        } else {
          signedIn = false;
        }
      });
   }
  return signedIn
};
```

2. Remove [vue-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-localstorage) and replace it with [@nuxtjs/universal-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/universal-storage)

See this also:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/7738